# How to make calculations extremely large numbers in python

Tags: python

I am trying to use the `pow` method on 256 bits number as the base and 1 bit to 4 thousand bits number as the exponent and then use modulo "n" on that number (n is a four thousand bits number).
meaning that the bigest number for the base is: `115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935`.
and the bigest number for the exponent is: `13182040934309431001038897942365913631840191610932727690928034502417569281128344551079752123172122033140940756480716823038446817694240581281731062452512184038544674444386888956328970642771993930036586552924249514488832183389415832375620009284922608946111038578754077913265440918583125586050431647284603636490823850007826811672468900210689104488089485347192152708820119765006125944858397761874669301278745233504796586994514054435217053803732703240283400815926169348364799472716094576894007243168662568886603065832486830606125017643356469732407252874567217733694824236675323341755681839221954693820456072020253884371226826844858636194212875139566587445390068014747975813971748114770439248826688667129237954128555841874460665729630492658600179338272579110020881228767361200603478973120168893997574353727653998969223092798255701666067972698906236921628764772837915526086464389161570534616956703744840502975279094087587298968423516531626090898389351449020056851221079048966718878943309232071978575639877208621237040940126912767610658141079378758043403611425454744180577150855204937163460902512732551260539639221457005977247266676344018155647509515396711351487546062479444592779055555421362722504575706910949375`.
But I am getting an error that says that those two numbers are to larg to convert to float.

> OverflowError: int too large to convert to float

Can someone help me perform this calculation with those values?

this is the tricky part of my code:

```
pre_key = pow(prime_g, private_number)
pre_key = pre_key % n
```

Comment: oh, I am trying to implement the Diffi helman key exchange so this calculation is necessary in the process :(

Comment: You're using the wrong `pow` function, aren't you? [mre]

Comment: @KellyBundy what is the right `pow` function to use? Maybe I'm missing something, but I think just to store the result of the largest 256 bit number to the power of the largest 4000 bit number would require 4.631683569492648e+80 bits (`(2**256-1) * math.log2(2**4000-1) + 1`). That's roughly the number of atoms in the universe.

Comment: @GordonAitchJay The built-in one. Not the one from `math`, which I think they're secretly using (judging by that error message). And it doesn't matter how large that intermediate result would be, as one shouldn't go though that anyway.

Answer (score -1):

As @Tim Roberts pointed out, I also don't think you should brute-force the program. That being said, you might be able to use the mpmath library, if you really NEED TO brute force your problem. I don't know, how well it handles numbers of that extreme size, but in principle you can allow for arbitrary precision.

Comment: Hmm, you make it sound like this can't trivially be done with basic Python...

Comment: I am dont trying not trying to brute force the program, I am trying to implement it